# Can you suggest good ways of generating URLS for viewing tagged content

Tags: url, tags, friendly-url

For example, here on stack overflow the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+php will give you all questions tagged with javascript and php.

The system I have allows tags with spaces in them, so the approach used here would not be a good fit for me.

What character would you use to separate the tags, so the URLs are still human readable, google readable and web browser compatible.

My gut feeling was to use commas. eg http://example.com/tagged/first+tag,second+tag

Any feedback or suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about dashes for spaces?
See the link for your question and you got it.

Comment: Looks like the consensus is to rewite the tags to use dashes for spaces, then leave the resulting tags separated by spaces same as here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick to using + as the tag separator and use something like an underscore '_' or just a %s for the spaces in the tag names?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind: putting "-" instead of  "_" is better in the eye of a search engine spider, and it is SEO rule

Comment: This is bs, there is no difference between - and _ for search engines. In what world would that make sense in any way?

Comment: @Joel L according to a video I watched quite a while ago (a google engineer was talking about SEO, but I don't remember the link); he claimed that using dash instead of underscore makes links more readable and he said they value them more...

Answer (score 0):

If your language has a URLEncode function then use that to modify your tags.

Answer (score 0):

How about + for spaces and - for tag spaces, then (just compiling best of both answers)?

I also have another tip, a little on the side, in case you haven`t thought of it. You can include non-answered questions with specific tags by adding [unanswered/](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/tags+link) before tagged.

See the related question [How to display questions with tag X that are unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015463/how-to-display-questions-with-tag-x-that-are-unanswered)